how to increase internal margin (padding?) of listings package for code
I am using the listings package to create framed boxes around code listings.
I am unable to change the internal margin between the frame and content.

The framesep parameter grows the size of the rendered frame. Vertically this has the desired effect, but horizontally the box extends into the left and right page margins. This is not the intended effect.

The rulesep parameter, according to the documentation "control the space between frame and listing". However it doesn't appear to do this. It appears to only control the distance between double-ruled edges.


I've searched the internet and documentation, and also this site, and can't find a solution to what I'm looking for: to keep the box fitting the actual width of the main body text, but to increase the internal margins (padding?).

The following is the smallest MWE I could create that illustrates the two parameters:
%% LyX 2.4.2.1 created this file.  For more info, see https://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[fontsize=10,oneside,english]{scrbook}
\usepackage{berasans}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{cmtl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage[paperwidth=6in,paperheight=9in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{microtype}
\setstretch{1.1}

\makeatletter
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% User specified LaTeX commands.
% Added by lyx2lyx
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{listings}
\renewcommand{\lstlistingname}{Listing}

\begin{document}

\subsubsection*{FrameSep Example}

The following uses \texttt{framsesep=30pt}, the default is 3.

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},frame=single,framesep=30pt,rulesep=2pt,framerule={0.1mm},aboveskip={\bigskipamount},language={python}]
from numpy import random

x = random.randint(100)

print(x)
\end{lstlisting}


\subsubsection*{RuleSep Example}

The following uses \texttt{rulesep=20pt}, the default is 2.

\begin{lstlisting}[basicstyle={\footnotesize\ttfamily},frame=single,framesep=3pt,rulesep=20pt,framerule={0.1mm},aboveskip={\bigskipamount},escapechar={\%},language={python}]
from numpy import random

x = random.randint(100)

print(x)
\end{lstlisting}

\end{document}


The resulting image illustrates the problem:


I am using lyx, but the MWE code was exported as latex, and the pdflatex command used to create the PDF shown above.

You also need to set the xleftmargin=30pt and xrightmargin=30pt for example for the first 'FrameSep' example.

thank @tom - so using framesep together with xleftmargin and xrightmargin works when the amounts are all set the same.
can I ask where I would find such information?
the official PDF documentation doesn't explain it at all and there appear to be no user guides or tutorials.

In the document, from what I understand that section (page 37) 4.3.9 Margins and line shape which influence the margin for main contents and section (page 38) 4.3.10 Frames which influence the frame behaviours without changing to main contents margin.

Thanks - I was looking t pages 37, 38 and 29.  The documentation is poor in my humble opinion, so I guess it takes someone with lots of experience to interpret what they really man. Thanks again for cracking this puzzle.

I don't see how to do it with the listings package, but it can be easily done with the minted package using the framesep option (see the \setminted command on line 10):
\documentclass[8pt]{extarticle}
\usepackage{microtype}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Tex Gyre Termes}
\setsansfont{Tex Gyre Adventor}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{colorful}
\setminted[unixconfig]{breaklines,fontsize=\footnotesize,frame=single,framesep=50pt}

\begin{document}
\parskip 6pt
\parindent 0pt

Test of minted listing with expanded internal margins:

\begin{minted}{unixconfig}
# QUEUE AND PROCESS OWNERSHIP
#
# The mail_owner parameter specifies the owner of the Postfix queue
# and of most Postfix daemon processes.  Specify the name of a user
# account THAT DOES NOT SHARE ITS USER OR GROUP ID WITH OTHER ACCOUNTS
# AND THAT OWNS NO OTHER FILES OR PROCESSES ON THE SYSTEM.  In
# particular, don't specify nobody or daemon. PLEASE USE A DEDICATED
# USER.
#
mail_owner = postfix
\end{minted}

\end{document}

I used a huge value of 50pt to illustrate it is working. Note also this is a separation on all sides: top, bottom, left and right.
I ran this MWE under linux using the lualatex engine.

Note that installing minted is somewhat involved as it requires python be installed on your system as well as the python Pygments library.
